# arch_prtcl C++ prototype

Tags: c++, prototype, glibc

For **arch_prctl** the man [page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/arch_prctl.2.html) states:

> As of version 2.7, glibc provides no prototype for  arch_prctl(). You have to declare it yourself for now.  This may be fixed in future glibc versions.

Compiling a C programm with clang works well but throws a warning

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'arch_prctl' is invalid in C99

However trying to compile a C++ with clang++ fails with

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'arch_prctl'

**So, how can I declare the required prototype myself?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to realise, that glibc probably does not support arch_prctl at all. So one has to do the coresponding syscall yourself:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int arch_prctl(int code, unsigned long addr)
{    
    return syscall(SYS_arch_prctl, code, addr);
}
```

Comment: You can do something like this to find out: `objdump -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so | grep arch_prctl`

Answer (score 0):

From the same man page:

> The arch_prctl() function sets architecture-specific process or
>   thread state.  code selects a subfunction and passes argument addr to
>   it; addr is interpreted as either an unsigned long for the "set"
>   operations, or as an unsigned long *, for the "get" operations.

So if you're doing set operations you should probably declare it like:

```
int arch_prctl(int code, unsigned long addr);
```

And for get:

```
int arch_prctl(int code, unsigned long *addr);
```

However, the system call in the Linux kernel gets defined like [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/syscalls.h#L47):

```
/* X86_64 only */
/* kernel/process_64.c */
asmlinkage long sys_arch_prctl(int, unsigned long);
```

And it later on [casts](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/um/syscalls_64.c#L74) it to a pointer anyway:

```
long sys_arch_prctl(int code, unsigned long addr)
{
    return arch_prctl(current, code, (unsigned long __user *) addr);
}
```

So writing any one of the declarations should work just fine as long as you are aware of the two different semantics and use them properly.